# What date to use as a post date? date_gmt or modified_date_gmt

Tags: posts, rest-api, date

I am consuming a rest service with the posts, and get both date_gmt and modified_date_gmt ...

What realy is the difference ? Is the modified_date a publish date also?

Any way, if I am presenting only one "News date", which date should I present as the most liable source ?

Answer (score 1):

Publish date - The date on which a post or page is created/Published

Modified_date - The date of the post with recent modification

If you are presenting only one "News date", you can use `modified_date` because news are always updating. The the users can easily understand.